# How to move images in amazon's S3 to Pinterest

Tags: amazon-s3, pinterest

I have lots of images stored in amazon's S3. As amazon's S3 doesn't provide a image viewing interface, I want to move these images to Pinterest.

I know Pinterest also store their images in amazon's S3. So it there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way available to transfer bulk images from S3 to Pinterest. You will have to use third part tools like www.tailwindapp.com but that too you cannot move directly from S3. You have to download that to your machine and then upload through www.tailwindapp.com.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know what to do now. :-)